# Uploading JPG image to Server in Android

Tags: java, android, performance

I have a curious question. When decode a JPG image in Bitmap, it take very high memory as JPG is a compressed format.So for 0.5 MB JPG image, bitmap is almost 4 MB.
My question is if I want to upload an image, I can just read it from file and send it to server i.e. I do NOT need to load it in Bitmap.
Have anybody ever tried this?
Does it makes sense?

Thanks for help.

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you are asking about, but aren't you looking for something like this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#compress(android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat, int, java.io.OutputStream) ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible. You don't need to covert jpg to bitmap to upload it to server.

You can consider using a higher level API like http://loopj.com/android-async-http/. Please see the section "Uploading Files with RequestParams" for more details.

Answer (score 0):

jpg is a format to store compressed images into files. It is practical because it takes less memory than the raw bitmap format, where the color values of all pixels in the image are explicitly present in the data.

You do need to decompress the jpg file in order to display it, however **the best way to send it would be to use the compressed jpg file** (no need to load the bitmap, just send the data in the file).

Note that JPEG compression is *lossy*, meaning that the reduction in size comes with a degradation in quality from the original source image. (see the thorough and well illustrated wikipedia entry:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jpg).